# C++: using namespace directive for non-existing namespace

Tags: c++

I am tryting to compile following code with g++ (version 7.5.0)

```
using namespace nspace;
int main()
{
        return 0;
}
```

It gives error as follow

```
$ g++ above_code.cpp 
namespaces_mystery1.cpp:1:17: error: ‘nspace’ is not a namespace-name
 using namespace nspace;
                 ^~~~~~
namespaces_mystery1.cpp:1:23: error: expected namespace-name before ‘;’ token
 using namespace nspace;
                       ^
```

Above behaviour is what I have expected.

But when I try to compile following code, it compiles fine without error like above.

```
using namespace std;
int main()
{
        return 0;
}
```

Why this different behaviour for namespace named **std** compared to namespace named **nspace**

Comment: Say hello to a GCC bug https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=29556 (14 year old bug, no less).

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica:  Do you have an answer for this up your sleeve? I don't like the "duplicate"; am happy to reopen. I *think* a compiler is allowed to effectively hardcode the statement "namespace std{};"

Comment: @Bathsheba - The duplicate (chain) is sound.

Answer (score 1):

The namespace `nspace` doesn't exist at the point `using namespace nspace;` is encountered, whereas the `std` namespace does. The latter could be true due to implicit or explicit inclusion of facets of the C++ standard library, or the compiler itself might even hardcode it.

If you had written

```
namespace nspace{}
```

before the `using` statement, then compilation would succeed.

Comment: I'm pretty certain there is no inclusion going on

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response. But can you please share more light on " implicit or explicit inclusion of facets of the C++ standard library". Because I expected error in first case. But what puzzles me is the second case.

Comment: The compiler probably has some implicit `std::` namespace identifiers "baked" into the compiler itself.  Probably for intrinsics, such as `std::abs` mapping to an intrinsic assembly instruction rather than being a function call or even an inline function call.